# Make https the default

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ssl, website

I have my domain and hosting setup to use https, and no normal http.

The only thing I use this for is webmail, and so I don't even want to offer normal http.

At the moment, I have to manually go to https://mysite.com, is there any way I can set things up so when I go to mysite.com it automatically loads the https version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's instruction for achieving this in Apache:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the previous answer:
you enable the unencrypted http access and set it up to do nothing but a redirect to the https access.